# Python search logs using wildcard options

Tags: python, search, python-re

I have a very large netflow dataset that looks something like this:

```
192.168.1.3  www.123.com
192.168.1.6  api.123.com
192.168.1.3  blah.123.com
192.168.1.3  www.google.com
192.168.1.6  www.xyz.com
192.168.1.6  test.xyz.com
192.168.1.3  3.xyz.co.uk
192.168.1.3  www.blahxyzblah.com
....
```

I also have a much smaller dataset of wildcarded domains that look like this:

```
*.xyz.com
api.123.com
...
```

I'd like to be able to search my dataset and find all of the matches using python. So in the example above, I would match on:

```
192.168.1.6  www.xyz.com
192.168.1.6  test.xyz.com
192.168.1.6  api.123.com
```

My attempt to use the `re` module but cannot get it to match on anything.

```
for f in offendingsites:
    for l in logs:
        if re.search(f,l):
            print(l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offending sites you have are not regexes, they are shell wildcards. However, you could use [`fnmatch.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate) to convert them to regexes:

```py
for f in offendingsites:
    r = fnmatch.translate(f)
    for l in logs:
        if re.search(r, l):
            print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`fnmatch.fnmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) to do wildcard pattern searching.

**Demo:**

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

with open("wildcards.txt") as offendingsites, open("dataset.txt") as logs:
    for f in offendingsites:
        for l in logs:
            f, l = f.strip(), l.strip() # Remove whitespace
            if fnmatch(l, f):
                print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
192.168.1.6  www.xyz.com
192.168.1.6  test.xyz.com
```